# Getting " 404 - not found: /v1//wallet/create" while creating a wallet using http async request

Tags: wallet, eosio-code

I have build EOS locally on ubuntu 17.10 using autobuild script using (./eosio_build.sh). and then installed the executables using
1. $ cd build
2. $ sudo make install

I've started keosd using the below command:

keosd  --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8899 --http-validate-host=false

I am using a Scala Wrapper of async-http based [library](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/Scala-API-Wrapper) to create wallet on my local machine. When I run the program, I am getting the below error:

> org.nsjames.utils.EOSApiException: {"code":404,"message":"Not
>   Found","error":{"code":0,"name":"exception","what":"unspecified","details":[]}}
>           at org.nsjames.utils.Client$.org$nsjames$utils$Client$$responseToStringResponse(Client.scala:51)
>           at org.nsjames.utils.Client$$anon$2.onCompleted(Client.scala:38)
>           at org.nsjames.utils.Client$$anon$2.onCompleted(Client.scala:37)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.AsyncCompletionHandler.onCompleted(AsyncCompletionHandler.java:68)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.getContent(NettyResponseFuture.java:234)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.done(NettyResponseFuture.java:269)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.finishUpdate(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:239)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler.handleChunk(HttpHandler.java:120)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler.handleRead(HttpHandler.java:149)
>           at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:76)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>           at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>           at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>           at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
>           at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>           at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>           at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>           at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>           at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

And when I look at the keosd console, It says: 
[image: 404 Not found]

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error was coming due to an extra "/" in the URI. This [pull request](http://github.com/EOSEssentials/Scala-API-Wrapper/pull/2) fixes this issue